# Best way to get and print formatted datetime?

Tags: c, time, printing, pascal

I am the occasional programmer that mostly uses Pascal and now I have to write some C-programs.

I want to print current time in my preferred format and after studying several C-tutorials I come up with:

```
time_t now;
struct tm *t;
char buffer[80];
time( &now );
t = localtime( &now );
strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

7 lines that in Free Pascal or Delphi requires just one line:

```
writeln(datetimetostr(now));
```

or if you don't want to use the global system settings:

```
writeln(FormatDateTime('DD MM YYYY',now));
```

Now I am certain that the c-world possesses pre-cooked higher level functions like those above.

But how do I find them?

And what is the best way to print the current time in system or custom format?

Comment: `Now I am certain` ? Why? `And what is the best way` How to measure "best"? `7 lines that` Technically you omitted `time`, `localtime` and `strftime` error checking. If you don't like that C has multiple statements and other languages have one, then don't use it. You can remove newlines, if you don't like them. In my opinion you presented a "fine way" to print current localtime in the request format.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I am certain that the c-world possesses pre-cooked higher level functions like those above.

Not really, no, at least not as part of the standard library.  Without using any third-party library or tools, that’s pretty much how it’s done - get a `time_t` value (number of seconds since the start of the epoch), convert it to a `struct tm` (which is broken down into year, month, day, hour, minute, second), pass that `struct tm` value to `strftime` along with a target buffer and a format string, write the contents of the buffer to the output stream.

You can consolidate some steps like alk has shown, but I don’t recommend doing that - it makes the code harder to read and debug.

Timestamps are regularly used for operations other than display, so making them a numeric type makes operations like comparisons or arithmetic more straightforward.  The tradeoff is that formatting them for output requires extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

> *But how do I find them?*

You won’t, because they do not exist, at least not as part of C/POSIX.

Still, there might be third party libraries providing more or less what you need.

If you want fewer lines and fewer variables you could just do:

```
char buffer[80];
strftime(buffer, sizeof buffer,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&((time_t){time(NULL)})));
puts(buffer);
```

Otherwise just roll your own:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char * format_date_time(const char * f, time_t t)
{
  static char buffer[80]; /* This is not thread safe! */
  strftime(buffer, sizeof buffer, f, localtime(&t));
  return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
  puts(format_date_time("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time(NULL)));
}
```

To answer your second question:

> *And what is the best way to print the current time in system or custom format?*

I feel the way you did it is fine.

Comment: Are there any 3rd party libraries to be recommended?